# What does @z mean in Python

Tags: python, search-engine

I'm reading someone else's code and I don't understand what is the use of `@z` here:

```
x = np.linalg.inv(P)@z
```

and when i Google `@z` ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%40z%20python&rlz=1C1UEAD_frFR988FR988&sxsrf=APq-WBsosm-LtRzjIkITKb_M5pxQor3New%3A1645310035200&ei=U3ARYun1C4GWaZTUiYAI&ved=0ahUKEwip68XB6Yz2AhUBSxoKHRRqAoAQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%40z%20python&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIICAAQFhAKEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgcIABBHELADOgQIABAeOgYIABAKEB46BggAEAUQHkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFDMBlijCGC1CmgBcAF4AIABOIgBaZIBATKYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)), it seems that the search engine ignores the `@`, how come?

Comment: Perhaps you weren't aware of the name of the @ symbol ('at'), although that seems unlikely in an age where even the homeless have e-mail addresses, but in general it's a good idea to try searching for the name of a symbol if a search including the symbol doesn't turn up anything.

Comment: You can also search for “python [@] symbol”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` refers to the [matrix multiplication operator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

From the `numpy` docs:

> The @ operator can be used as a shorthand for np.matmul on ndarrays.
>
> ```
> x1 = np.array([2j, 3j])
> x2 = np.array([2j, 3j])
> x1 @ x2
> (-13+0j)
> ```